# How to add a sort image in display tag?

Tags: jsp, struts, jsp-tags, displaytag

I am using display tag for showing list data.This is how I 'setup' display:table in my jsp.

```
<display:table  name="TABLE_DATA_LIST" uid="list" style="width:100%;table-layout: fixed;" requestURI="/list/something.action" export="false" defaultsort="2" defaultorder="ascending" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" partialList="true"    size="${TOTAL_RESULT}" htmlId="list" pagesize="${PAGE_SIZE}">
```

Now apart from all columns I want to have a customized image attached to every column so that while clicking on it result data can be sorted .Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

It can be updated by updating the respective CSS class in your page.
Usualy the CSS class be like 
`th.order1 a {
background: url("../images/table-sort-down.png") no-repeat scroll right center transparent;
    padding-right: 14px;}`
which you can update based on your images.

there will be two classes for ascending and descending. Changing these classes will result in your custom images when user sorts.